# What does "W.C" on Izumi Curtis's slippers mean?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

What does "W.C" mean? My guess was "water closet" - basically toilet slippers. If my guess is true why does she wear it? Is it a popular thing in Japan or Germany for housewives to go out with toilet slippers?

[image: "W.C" slippers]

[[image: Izumi Curtis]]

Comment: [check this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FullmetalAlchemist/comments/1k4yx4/anyone_know_what_the_initials_on_izumis_sandals/)

Answer (score 3):

The user Tombow on http://www.fullmetal-alchemist.com/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t12824-450.html stated:

> W.C. = Water Closet. = toilet.
>
> In Japan, in Inns and other places like that sometimes they have public bathrooms (toilet) and some of them have slippers to be used inside that bathroom, often with W.C. written like that, and, yes, some of these bathroom slippers are exactly like what Izumi is wearing. (I saw them in some other anime and manga, too, but I got these pics form Google. XDD)

Comment: Not just inns - if you're at a restaurant with tatami rooms (where you take off your shoes to sit down), you'll have a set of guest slippers to travel about the restaurant (ie, to the drink bar), and a separate set to switch to once you reach the bathroom.

Comment: Remember that I was quoting somebody else. These are not my words.